# C# LINQ OrderBy several clauses

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm currently working on an application in ASP.NET MVC 4.5. I need to write a LINQ query to order a list of Projects by different StatusIds.

Given is a list of Projects with this ViewModel:

```
public class ProjectVm 
{
   public int ProjectId { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public Status StatusId { get; set; }
}
```

My project status enum:

```
public enum Status : byte
{
    Draft = 1,
    Pending = 2,
    Validated = 3,
    Refused = 4
}
```

The idea is to bring the `List<ProjectVm>` in a certain order, thus first ordered by ***1 Draft***, second by ***2 Pending***, third by ***4 Refused*** and fourth by ***3 Validated***.

My current query looks like this:

```
projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.StatusId).ToList();
```

Unfortunately this query doesn't respect the desired order (4 comes before 3).

Do you know how to apply a condition on this query to bring the projects into the right order (1, 2, 4, 3) ?

Thanks!

Comment: x => ((Status)x.StatusId).ToString())

Comment: @Compufreak's Comparer implementation in the answers below is IMHO the best and most reusable and maintanable way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use several orderings, the first one with `OrderByDescending`, then the rest with `ThenByDescending`:

```
projects = projects
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.StatusId == Status.Draft)
    .ThenByDescending(p => p.StatusId == Status.Pending)
    .ThenByDescending(p => p.StatusId == Status.Refused)
    .ThenByDescending(p => p.StatusId == Status.Validated)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not a clean way to do it completely inline - you *could* do something like:

```
projects.OrderBy(x => x == Status.Validated ? int.MaxValue : (int)x.StatusId)
```

to force Validated to be at the end, but I would write a function:

```
private int CustomOrder(Status status)
{
    switch(status)
    {
       // force Validated to the end
        case Status.Validated:
            return int.MaxValue;
        default:
            return (int)status;
    }
}
```

and call it from the query:

```
projects.OrderBy(x => CustomOrder(x))
```

Since you can add comments and organize the code to make it clearer what your intent is.

Another option would be to put the values in array in the order you want, then order by their position in the array:

```
Status[] order = new [] {Draft, Pending, Refused, Validated};

projects.OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(order,x));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static int MyCustomOrder (Status status)
{
    switch (status)
    {
        case Status.Draft     : return 1;
        case Status.Pending   : return 2;
        case Status.Validated : return 4;
        case Status.Refused   : return 3;

        default: return -1;
    }
}
```

And now:

```
var result = projects.OrderBy (x => MyCustomOrder (x.StatusId));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really pretty, but should work:

```
projects.OrderBy(x => x.StatusId).ThenBy(c => c.StatusId == Status.Validated ? 1 : 0).ToList();
```

Otherwise you need to provide your own Comparer:

```
class StatusComparer : IComparer<Status>
        {
            public int Compare(Status x, Status y)
            {
                if (x.Equals(y)) return 0;
                return (x > y || x.Equals(Status.Validated)) ? 1 : -1;
            }
        }
```

And then call:

```
projects.OrderBy(x => x.StatusId, new StatusComparer()).ToList();
```

Or do something like the other people here proposed ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
projects.OrderBy(x => x.StatusId == Status.Validated).ThenBy(x => x.StatusId)
```

Puts all the pending at the end, then sorts within that rule by StatusID. Two simple operations and likely to be processed well by any provider.

```
projects.OrderBy(x => x.StatusId == Status.Validated ? int.MaxValue : (int)x.StatusId)
```

A single operation, which is hence likely faster, that re-assigns the `3` for `Pending` to `int.MaxValue` before the sort.

I'd try the second first as the likely more efficient, but the second is worth noting as a general approach too.

Comment: You probably mean Validated instead of Pending.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var projectList= projects.OrderBy(x => (int)x.StatusId).ToList();
```

Comment: This does exactly the same thing as without the int cast.